# vba code for excel - to encoding gibberish to hebrew

Tags: excel, vba, encoding, hebrew

i have files that open with excel.
when i open the file the text is like gibberish.
i need to encode  - tools-internet option - general-encode - hebrew iso-visual
and then the file turn to hebrew

there is a vba code that do that ?

thanks,
omri

Comment: @omri Please mark my answer as correct!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have a way to test this, so I am just taking a shot:

```
Excel.ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.Encoding = msoEncodingHebrew
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function from ADODB Stream, with the following code.

Page 1255 is the original Hebrew page. 
And you need to reference the latest Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library.
(Tools/References)

```
Public Function CorrectHebrew(gibberish As String) As String

  Dim inStream As ADODB.stream

  Set inStream = New ADODB.stream
  inStream.Open
  inStream.Charset = "WIndows-1255"
  inStream.WriteText gibberish
  inStream.Position = 0 ' bring it back to start preparing for the ReadText
  inStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
  CorrectHebrew = inStream.ReadText ' return the corrected text

  inStream.Close

End Function
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as the answer.
Thanks @Jaqen_H'ghar for putting the Function and End-Function into the code block.

Comment: Thanks @pashute, great answer